# Unable to retrieve Application State in Model class

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, application-state

Im facing a problem in one of MVC projects, that problem is about retrieving values from Application State object.

I am storing some value into the Application state in `Application_Start()` method of `Global.axas.cs` in this manner:

```
//var str = Obj.DecryptString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ToString());
//Application["connString"] = str;

Application["connString"] = Obj.DecryptString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ToString());
```

I have made sure the value from `web.config` has been successfully retrieve at this point through debugging.

After this step I’m trying to retrieve this value in one of my `Model Class` in this manner:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(Application["connString"].ToString());
```

But here I’m getting a `NullReferenceException` `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Now this is very confusing for me here that if the value has been successfully retrieved and stored in `AapplicationState` at the point of `Application_Start()` than why isn’t it available in my model class, aren't the ApplciatiopnSate available throughout the application?

Comment: Just been through this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87316/A-walkthrough-to-Application-State and I cannot see a difference between how you are using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is not to keep the connection string in the Application variable. Rather you can declare a static method which can return the connection string.Store the connection string in a static variable as shown below

```
public class Utility
{
    static string connectionString;    
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            connectionString = Obj.DecryptString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ToString());
        return connectionString;
    }
}
```

Configuration files are cached, henceforth you need not worry about performance of reading the files every time the method is called

Comment: One of the main reasons I’m putting it there is as you see it in encrypted format and needs to be decrypted before use, so I don’t want this `reading`, `decryption` to happen every time a data connection has to be made in some method which will increase the time and would be redundant practice.

Comment: Thankyou for providing the alternative but even if configuration files are cached the `DecryptString` method will have to be called every time this method is called? My main concern is to avoid using this heavy method as much as possible.